# Two problems in SharePoint Search

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I have made a page to show search results. In that page I have added those search web parts to display results.

1.When I search something, in some search results it shows strange character as shown in screenshot below. Is this character encoding issue? How do I fix this?

[image]

2.Second problem is (which I think is not a problem but a feature) when I search something, at the bottom of page it says "About 28 results" and when I go to next result page then it says "19 results". Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "About xx results" because the Search does not bother to do a full count of all results, for performance reasons. It just works with a set number of records per query.

The encoding should be due to some error in the encoding of the crawled resource (document, file e.g) and is not a Search error per se.

Comment: The search results page and the document which it is crawling has encoding set to UTF-8.